# "self" placeholder var for IAM user policy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

You define policies that Grant access to resources generally but can I use a policy that grants access to the IAM user it's applied to?

I guess I want a bucket access policy but for an IAM user. I want to attach a policy to a user that says give a specific iam role access to me.

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by "give a specific iam role access to me"? Are you simply asking "How can I grant a specific user access to an Amazon S3 bucket by doing it in IAM rather than doing it in S3"?

Comment: no just used that as an example. I want to do the reverse of what you normally do with policies. I want to apply a policy to a user that gives a specific role access to it. Rather than apply a policy to a role that gives it access to a specific user

Comment: What do you mean by "that gives a specific role access to it"? Can you expand on this with an example?

Comment: I want to give an iam role access to modify an iam user account so when that role is assumed it has access to modify this iam user. Instead of creating an iam policy that gives this role access to the iam user and applying it to the role i was wondering if i could do the reverse. id have a policy applied to the user account that gives the role access to itself.

Comment: @red888 IAM users are not resources, they are principals.  Please provide a simple yet concrete, meaningful example of what problem you are trying to solve and what specific actions such a role would make possible.

Comment: @red888 It appears that your concept of a User and a Role do not match what they are and how they are used. That's fine -- this is a place for learning. If you can please explain your end-goal (rather than talking about roles and users), then we'll be able to explain how to best achieve that goal within an AWS environment. Please Edit your question and provide a sample scenario of what (not how!) you wish to achieve.